# getting a filename in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code to get a list of file names in a particular directory

```
import sys,os

data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))]
print data_files
```

the output is something like

```
[['bar.py',  'foo.py', 'foo.pyc', 'fooBar', 'fooBar.py', 'tar.py', 'tar.pyc']]
```

I want to parse this list and pass only a particular filename to another function

for example : I want to parse the list?( is it a list?) above and pass only tar.py to another function , ie the name tar , so as another function can use it like

```
import filename ( in this case tar)
```

I am new to python and tried a lot of list parsing stuff but could not extract the name . any help would be appreciated

I am using python 2.7

Thank you for your time

EDIT:

I figured out how to parse the list

```
data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))]
hello = data_files[0]
print hello[0].split(".")[0]
```

the problem is when I try assigning the file name to a variable like

```
var = hello[0].split(".")[0]
```

and use `import var`

but I am not sure if python allows importing modules like this because it does not consider var as a variable but a module name . how can I overcome this

Comment: I want to get the file name , for ex :   the list comes out as [['bar.py']] , I want the filename to be just bar , so as an import statement such as  "import (filename)" works

Comment: >"bar.py".split(".")[0]
>"bar"

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how do I parse the list ,I just cnt seem to do it with normal list parsing

Comment: What do you mean by normal list parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which index your element is at, you can do `file_list[index_of_your_element].split('.')[0]`, for example:

```
file_list = ['bar.py',  'foo.py', 'foo.pyc', 'fooBar', 'fooBar.py', 'tar.py', 'tar.pyc']
print l[5].split('.')[0] == 'tar'
```

Will print `true`. Your question is kinda confusing, what do you know about the element, and how do you want to use it?

Comment: hi , Thank you for your answer , I used the following code to parse the list
data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))]
hello = data_files[0]
print hello[0].split(".")[0]

so I get the name of the file I want , but the problem is this file name is assigned to a variable , hence import var  will not look for the variable but var  . hence I cannot import the file I want

Comment: Use `__import__(module_name)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused on what you mean by list parsing. It is a list and if you want to remove all the file extensions you can do it with a list comprehension and split as fastreload suggested.

```
new_list = [x.split('.')[0] for x in data_files]
```

If you need to step through the list looking at each file you can do that with

```
for file in data_files:
    your code goes here
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited your post when I was supposed to edit mine.